Dynamically infer the return type of a function that returns a component
I am trying to get rid of the "any" in return type of the getFilterComponent function:
import { type default as React } from "react";

type filterType = 'filterA' | 'filterC' | 'filterB'

interface FilterProps<DATA extends Object> {
  type:filterType ,
  data: DATA
}

function FilterACComponent({data: {a}}: FilterProps<{a: string}>){
  return a
}

function FilterBComponent({data:{b}}: FilterProps<{b: string}>){
  return b
}

const getFilterComponent =(type?: filterType): React.FC<FilterProps<any>> => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'filterA':
    case 'filterC':
      return FilterACComponent;
    case 'filterB':
      return FilterBComponent;
    default:
      return () => null;
  }
};


I tried doing this but as you can see it is stupid because i have to hardcode the types for all the component in the place where i am writing the function:
const getFilterComponent = <T extends filterType>(
  type?: T
): T extends 'filterAComponent' 
  ? React.FC<FilterProps<{ a: string }>>
  : T extends 'filterBComponent'
  ? React.FC<FilterProps<{ b: string }>>
  : React.FC<FilterProps<any>>

In the real example, there are many types of filters so i need a dynamic way to infer the returned component props.
It would also be preferred to keep the current way of passing the DATA since this way i can keep the data type of each filter in it's own component file.
I also would like to keep it a switch statement instead of having a map if possible because multiple types can have the same component.
The getFilterComponent is called at run time, so it is not statically called.

The code in the question produces some unrelated diagnostic errors. Are you looking for a mapped type with an overload signature like this? If so, I can write an answer from the code in that playground — but if not, can you edit the question to fix the diagnostic errors and clarify?

Thanks for the response. I fixed the code and added extra info.

If I am understanding correctly you are fine with individually setting the types but do not want to hardcode them all?
Would something like this achieve what you are trying to do.
// defining the various filters and their corresponding props
type FilterProps = {
  filterA: { a: string };
  filterB: { b: string };
};

// Create another type that represents all filterComponents
type FilterComponentType = {
  [K in keyof FilterProps]: React.FC<{ data: FilterProps[K] }>;
};

// all the components
const FilterComponents: FilterComponentType = {
  filterA: ({ data }) => <p>{`this be filter A with props: ${data.a}`}</p>,
  filterB: ({ data }) => <p>{`this be filter B with props: ${data.b}`}</p>,
};

// gets the filter based off a 'filterA' or `filterB`
function getFilterComponent<K extends keyof FilterComponentType>(
  type: K
): FilterComponentType[K] {
  return FilterComponents[type];
}

After writing this out, I am actually unsure if this does fit the bill.But this does alleviate the need for an any or hardcoding the filters like you were

Thanks for the answer.
It seems to me that your FilterProps type is not the same as mine. The filter props need to allow shared props between filterA and filterB.  I have other shared Props as well but i kinda simplifed it above.
It is only the data field that is different for each filter type
other thing is that i would prefer to use a switch statement because it is possible
that multiple filter types, share the same component.
